# Blockquote when code sample makes one-line code difficult to read?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, code-formatting

Just saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16235877/1983854) in which the OP indicates a code in plain text:

find /opt/backup/test -name "*.gz" -exec smbclient -A /opt/backup/smbclient_authentication.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c put '{}' \

I wanted to use code-sample to format it, but I got this:

```
find /opt/backup/test -name "*.gz" -exec smbclient -A /opt/backup/smbclient_authentication.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c put '{}' \
```

which is not easy to read.

Would it be correct to blockquote it instead?

> find /opt/backup/test -name "*.gz" -exec smbclient -A
>   /opt/backup/smbclient_authentication.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c put '{}' \

It was finally edited like this:

```
$ find /opt/backup/test -name "*.gz" -exec smbclient -A \
/opt/backup/smbclient_authentication.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c put '{}' \
```

but I do not want just to focus in this case, but in general.

Is there any rule (written or "in the air") to handle this code presentation?

Comment: The last edit is the correct one.  This will work in all cases except for those languages like Python which are whitespace sensitive, in which case it is better just to leave it in its original form.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertHarvey, so it is better to Blockquote when having a too long line to code-sample it.

Comment: Horizontal scrollbars are not the end of the world.  I try to avoid them, but sometimes that is not possible.